# Running C/C++ Executables in Docker Container

Tags: c++, docker, jenkins, openwrt

In my company we are using openwrt as linux distibution for our embedded systems. It's an aarch64 system with a cortex-a53 chip. We only program in C and C++, using some shell-scripts or python scripts for testing. (and of course unit tests in C and C++)

Unfortunately, our build processes are very long and we include many applications/executables and libaries that we often don't need when we just want to test one specific application.

My first idea was that we build smaller firmware versions, different sub-systems and also deploy only those to specific controllers.

The idea behind this is that we write a mock for each software component for all interfaces. Then in a firmware only the base image, the software component to be tested, the mock and all required libraries is installed.

But with 40-50 applications, you quickly have 40-50 different firmwares to build.

I imagine the process as follows:

1. with a build process our build server (Jenkins) creates all libraries, all applications and all mock applications as artifacts.
2. with a nightly build in our Jenkins server, new artifacts are created every 24h at the latest in any case.
3. there should be a total of 40-50 Docker containers that have the base image of OpenWRT + a main application + a mock copied in.
4. these containers should be written with Dockerfiles and automatically uses the latest state of the needed artifacts.
5. the Docker containers are also available on the Jenkins server and can be downloaded and run whenever needed.

The sense of the whole: I would like to make possibilities possible for the testing of individual components beforehand software-based, without which due to Bug's of colleagues in other components a test on a test system is not possible.

A condition for it is naturally that the Mocks are likewise cleanly programmed - and evenly that the basis functionalities are available like the ubus of OpenWRT.

Of course, one could also test without an OpenWRT base system, but we in the software team like to use Windows, not only Ubuntu computers, as well as 32 bit and not 64 bit systems, etc. - perhaps some black sheep even uses a different compiler locally on their computer.

The idea with Docker and the OpenWRT base system is quite simple: a common, uniform build configuration and the same prerequisite for all tests.

I am still far away from automation, Docker is something I am dealing with for the first time (to my shame).

My problem is that "copying" a c/c++ executable into a container does not work. At least I always get an error when running the applications:
/bin/component_a: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
# base image
# FROM openwrtorg/rootfs:x86-64
FROM hibuddies/openwrt-aarch64
EXPOSE 22 443 80

# set maintainer
LABEL maintainer "m.doerflinger@ads-tec-energy.com"

# copy files
RUN echo "Copying files ..."

COPY /files/component_a /bin
RUN chmod a+x /bin/component_a
```

....

```
docker build -t test .
```

...

```
/bin/component_a
```

I am pretty sure that simply copying an executable is of course the cause of the problem, presumably the C program has simply been compiled in a wrong variant so that this is not executable.

But before I start racking my brains looking for a solution that may not be technically possible, a few questions for you:

1. is my idea technically possible at all?
2. can I even use the original build artifacts of a release image version / trunk image version for a Docker container?
3. how do I get a Docker container with OpenWRT base system to be as close as possible to the OpenWRT system on a final product later? I'm guessing that the various variants from Docker hub, such as hibuddies/openwrt-aarch64, are of limited use.
4. is the approach/variant from my dockerfile viable at all? Copying possible? I still don't quite understand the difference between the "COPY" and "ADD" commands.

I appreciate any hints, advice and from your experience with Docker! As I said, I'm new to the subject and am just learning the ropes. Please forgive me if I had misunderstood rough contexts after all.

Thanks for your answers!

Kind regards
Matthias

Comment: Can't you mount an external folder as a volume with `-v` ?

Comment: @Henrique Bucher: it should be possible to share the docker containers, so each software developer can use them, even in home office or offline.

Comment: I have the same issue - I support software for several distros and CPUs. But I copy the tarball with the sources to a base "cache" docker and inherit from it. I think the issue with your question is that it is too long and people here have a short attention span :)